prevent change quantities on cart page
I'm using combo offer woocommerce plugin to make a bundle product with specific item number of linked products.
I had unchecked this option:
"Buyer can change the quantity of combo products?"
so when I head to the product page I see really that I can't modify the items quantities.
But when I add the product to cart then view the cart it shows the quantities of included items of the combo product are able to be changed:

How can I prevent that please?
I've added this code to my activated plugin:
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'disable_quantity_change_for_combo_products', 10, 3);

function disable_quantity_change_for_combo_products($product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item) {
    // Check if the product type is 'wooco' (Combo Offer).
    if (isset($cart_item['data']) && 'wooco' === get_post_meta($cart_item['data']->get_id(), '_product_type', true)) {
        // Disable quantity input field by returning a hidden input field.
        return '<input type="hidden" name="cart[' . esc_attr($cart_item_key) . '][qty]" value="' . esc_attr($cart_item['quantity']) . '" />';
    }
    return $product_quantity;
}

But it did not help.

I have tested the plugin, creating a combo product with unchecked option "Buyer can change the quantity of combo products?" and I don't get any issue as you describe (see https://prnt.sc/RjmBOUB0tY2P). Note that I tested on Classic Cart page (not cart Block) within Storefront theme. So there is something else that is making trouble, it can be your theme, a plugin or some custom code you added.
